# Filter input array for PHP < 5.2

Tags: php, compatibility, filter-input

I have a code with a lot of using this function. but now i need do code compatible with PHP 5.1.6 (i dont have access to update PHP or install any extension), so I need some user definied function to declare it. I search on Google, but without success.
Do You have any idea how to solve this problem?
Thanks,
RS.

Comment: I don't know why was closed as not real question...Same problem here and the question is very straightforward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter functions are very powerful, and is a big work reproduce they.

If you want to reproduce it you can do:

```
if(!function_exists('filter_input_array'))
{
    function filter_input_array($type, $definition)
    {
        // Write code here
    }
}
```